# Creating NSShadow makes an error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsshadow

I'm making a white shadow in Objective-C and using the code

```
NSShadow *myShadow = [[NSShadow alloc]init];
[myShadow setShadowColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
```

and it seems to work fine, but when I'm trying to shorten it to

```
NSShadow *myShadow = [[[NSShadow alloc]init] setShadowColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
```

I get the error message "Initializing 'NSShadow *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'"
Anyone knows what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is the compiler doesn't like a variable of type `NSShadow *` being assigned `void` (the return type of `setShadowColor` and that expression as a whole).

You will need to use your two-line approach, which is easier to read and therefore maintain.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! But it would be even nicer if Apple made a class method called "shadowWithColor:" so I could write 
    NSShadow *myShadow = [NSShadow shadowWithColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];

Comment: ... looks like a job for a category to might like to write ;-)